# What word can be used if I mean to forcibly open a nailed crate?

Tags: single-word-requests

Two kids have put a cat in a large crate and nailed it shut. Now I want to free this cat.

> These brats have nailed the cat in this crate. I need a tool to ... this crate.

Open? Sure, but there must be a better word. Crack? Break? Force?

Comment: Normally it would be "pry open".

Comment: Or, 'jemmy' the crate.

Comment: @NigelJ I dunno, but doesn't  the word "jemmy" imply that we're opening the crate because we're burglars and want to steal whatever is hidden inside?

Comment: Not at all. A jemmy is just a tool. It's what one uses to force open a crate for whatever purpose.

Comment: @NigelJ just a note - this sense of jemmy or jimmy is not common in the US. Here it means to gain access by defeating, breaking, or bypassing some means of security. In the US,  we don't normally call prybars 'jimmies'. But you can jimmy a padlock with a prybar.

Comment: @PhilSweet For us, a 'jimmy' is something else. 'Jimmy Riddle' is rhyming slang for 'piddle' which is another word for a pee. And in proper rhyming slang, one drops off the rhyming part. So a 'jimmy' becomes a pee.

Comment: In British English we would say 'prise open' rather than 'pry'.

Answer (score 3):

**pry open**

[pry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pry) is defined (in this sense) as *to raise, move, or pull apart with a lever*.

The phrase "pry open" is an idiom that is commonly used to refer to opening a box, door, etc with a lever.  "Pry apart" might also be used, especially if the operation involved removing more than one piece from the object.

Answer (score 0):

What about "wrest" as in "I need a tool to wrest open this crate."

Or, "wrench" as in "I need a tool to wrench open this crate."

Or, "burst" as in "I need a tool to burst open/into this crate."

These words tend to pair another word like "open", which might not fit your definition of a single word request, but they might convey what you'd like.